# Conditional Variance of Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $B=(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ bethe one dimensional Brownian motion.

Let futheremore $s, t \in [0,1]$.

I want to know how to deduce following formulas:

1) $Var(B_t \vert B_1) = t - t^2$

2) $\mathbb{E}[B_s,B_t \vert B_1] = s/t\mathbb{E}[B_t^2 \vert B_1] $

My attempts:

I know that $\mathbb{E}[B_t \vert B_1]= tB_1$ and ${\displaystyle \operatorname {Var} (B_t|B_1)=\operatorname {E} ((B_t-\operatorname {E} (B_t\mid B_1))^{2}\mid B_t)}$ already holds,

futhermore, if $B_t$ is BM, then also $W_t := tB_{1/t}$.

But I don't see how to combine this facts to get 1) and 2).

Comment: By independent increments we have $$
\mathbb E[B_t\mid B_1] = \mathbb E[B_t-B_1+B_1\mid B_1] = \mathbb E[B_t-B_1] + B_1 = B_1,
$$
so I'm not sure why you say $\mathbb E[B_t\mid B_1]=tB_1$.

Comment: The problem is that $1 \ge t$, so you firstly need the trafo $W_{1/t} := 1/tB_{t}$

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail. Never mind.

Comment: For $E(B_s, B_t | B_1)$, do you mean $E(B_s B_t | B_1)$?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the density of $B_t$ is $$f_t(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} $$ and so the conditional density of $B_t$ given $B_u=b$, where $t<u$, is
$$
f_{t\mid u}(x\mid b) = \frac{f_t(x)f_{u-t}(b-x)}{f_u(b)}\propto \exp\left(-\frac{u(x-bt/u)^2}{2t(u-t)} \right),
$$
which is a normal distribution with mean $bt/u$ and variance $t(u-t)/u$ It follows that the conditional expectation and variance of $B_t$ given $B_u$ (where here $u=1$) are
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[B_t\mid B_1] &= tB_1\\
\mathsf{Var}(B_t\mid B_1) &= t(1-t).
\end{align}
The third expression seems like it should follow from
$$
\mathbb E[B_sB_t\mid B_1] = \mathbb E[(B_s/B_t)B_t^2\mid B_1],
$$
but I'm not certain about the computation.